# Newton method to solve $x^2-a=0$

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

> Consider a real number $a>0$. Show that the Newton method to solve the
>   equation $x^2-a=0$ is given by
>
> $$x^{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^k + \frac{a}{x^k}\right)$$

finding a zero of $f'$ is the same as finding a minimu of $f$, so that's what I did:

$$f'(x) = x^2 -a \implies f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}-ax $$

$$\nabla^2 f(x) d = -\nabla f(x)\implies 2xd = -(x^2-a)\implies d = \frac{-x^2+a}{2x}$$

so we get

$$x^{k+1}=x^k + \lambda_k\left(\frac{-x^2+a}{2x}\right)$$

Now I must find $\lambda_k$ minium of $f(x^{k+1})=\frac{\left(x^k + \lambda_k\left(\frac{-x^2+a}{2x}\right)\right)^3}{3}-a\left(x^k + \lambda_k\left(\frac{-x^2+a}{2x}\right)\right)$

how should I find $\lambda_k$ that minimizes $f$ above?

Comment: Can you just show instead that the limit of $x_k$ as $k\to\infty$ exists, and call it $x$ say, and then take the limit of both sides of the defining equation $x=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} x_{k+1}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}(x_k+\frac{a}{x_k})=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a}{x})$

Comment: just solve $f'(x^{k+1}) = 0$ for $\lambda_k$

Comment: @LinAlg I'm supposed to get $\lambda_k=1$ but $f'(x^{k+1})=0$ won give me that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks far too complicated: Just plugin your function $f(x) = x^2-a$ in the formula for [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)
$$x_{k+1} = x_k -\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)} = x_k -\frac{x_k^2-a}{2x_k}$$
$$= x_k -\frac{x_k^2}{2 x_k} + \frac{a}{2x_k} = x_k -\frac{1}{2}x_k + \frac{a}{2x_k}$$
and finally
$$ x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_k + \frac{a}{x_k}\right)$$

Comment: +1 for the first sentence :D

Comment: It's because I'm studying the Newton Method for optimization, so I need to arrive at this formula, I cannot use the direct methd for finding zeros

Comment: so the suggestion is to use $\lambda=1$